# How to make multiple ajax call synchronously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api, synchronisation

I want to make multiple ajax calls synchronously from my javascript code. I want to load the SharePoint Online Lists data using ajax call(rest api). I want to load data from the first list and after successfully load the first list data I want to load another list data. How can I load the data synchronously?

I have tried this with the 'async:false'. But I have marked that it has been not supported in some browser.

Please suggest me!

Thanks

Comment: I am the first one to say you should not use async:false .. but there is no Browser restriction. jQuery deprecated it when using Promises, But without Promises async:false should still work in any browser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the jQuery's when to get data as below:

```
function SPData() {
    function getJsonDataAsync(url) {
        // returning the $.ajax object is what makes the next part work...
        return $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json",
            headers: {
                accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
            }
        });
    }

    var requestURI1 = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List1')/items?&$orderby=Title"
    var requestURI2 = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List2')/items?&$orderby=Title"
    var requestURI3 = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List3')/items?&$orderby=Title"            
    var req1 = getJsonDataAsync(requestURI1);
    var req2 = getJsonDataAsync(requestURI2);
    var req3 = getJsonDataAsync(requestURI3);
    // now we can do the next line, because req1/2/3 are actually deferreds
    // being returned from $.ajax
    jQuery.when(req1, req2, req3).done(function(resp1, resp2, resp3) {
        /* do something with all of the requests here...
           resp1/2/3 correspond to the responses from each call and are each an
           array that looks like: [data, statusText, jqXHR], which means that your
           data is in resp1[0], resp2[0], etc. */
    });
}
```

Reference - [REST API multiple calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24744702/rest-api-multiple-lists-in-sharepoint)

You can also use the batch api as below:

Just add reference to `sp-rest-batch-execution.js` and after that try below code:

```
var getEndPoint1 = appweburl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List1')/items?&$orderby=Title";

var getEndPoint2 = appweburl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List2')/items?&$orderby=Title";

var getEndPoint3 = appweburl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('List3')/items?&$orderby=Title";

var commands = [];

batchRequest = new BatchRequest();
batchRequest.endpoint = getEndPoint1;
batchRequest.headers = { 'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose' }
commands.push({ id: batchExecutor.loadRequest(batchRequest), title: "Rest Batch Get Items 1" });

batchRequest = new BatchRequest();
batchRequest.endpoint = getEndPoint2;
batchRequest.headers = { 'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose' }
commands.push({ id: batchExecutor.loadRequest(batchRequest), title: "Rest Batch Get Items 2" });

batchRequest = new BatchRequest();
batchRequest.endpoint = getEndPoint3;
batchRequest.headers = { 'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose' }
commands.push({ id: batchExecutor.loadRequest(batchRequest), title: "Rest Batch Get Items 3" });


batchExecutor.executeAsync().done(function (result) {
    var d = result;
    var msg = [];
    $.each(result, function (k, v) {
        var command = $.grep(commands, function (command) {
            return v.id === command.id;
        });
        if (command.length) {
            msg.push("Command--" + command[0].title + "--" + v.result.status);
        }
    });

    console.log(msg.join('\r\n'));

}).fail(function (err) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

Works well in SPO - [SP-Rest-batch execution](https://github.com/SteveCurran/sp-rest-batch-execution)

If you are a fan of PnP JS like me, it also provides the batching as below:

```
var batchResults = [];
var batch = new $pnp.sp.createBatch();
$pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("List1").items.inBatch(batch).get().then(function(d) {
  batchResults.push({ 
    custom01: d 
  });
});
$pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("List2").items.inBatch(batch).get().then(function(d) {
  batchResults.push({ 
    custom02: d 
  });
});
$pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("List3").items.inBatch(batch).get().then(function(d) {
  batchResults.push({ 
    custom03: d 
  });
});

batch.execute().then(function() {
  console.log(batchResults);
});
```

**Update** - for using PnP js core in IE , you need to add below references as well. jQuery is not required:

[es6-promise](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise)

[fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch)

Usage:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/pathinyoursitecoll/es6-promise.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/pathinyoursitecoll/fetch.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/pathinyoursitecoll/pnp.js"></script>
```

Reference - [PnP JS core](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core)

Comment: Does PnP need jQuery? I thought it had its own HttpClient ..

Comment: my bad, jQuery is not required for PnP js, usually i have used it along with jQuery, so had mentioned that.

Answer (score 1):

You can call one Ajax call on success of another Ajax Call.

```
// Assign Lists Name to one Array;
var listNameArray =["List1","List2", "List3"]
// Call function To get List Item
getMutipleList(0,listNameArray)

//This function we can call it recursively on success of Ajax Call
var getMutipleList = function (count, listNameArray) {
    try {
        var Url = webUrl + "/_api/web/GetByTitle('" + listNameArray[count] + "')/items";
        getRequest(Url, true).then(function (data) {
            count++;
            if (count < listNameArray.length) {
                getMutipleList(count, listNameArray);
            }
            else {

                //code
            }
        }).fail(onFail)
    }
    catch (ex) {
        alert("Please try agian. Something went wrong.")
        console.log(ex.message);
    }
}


var baseRequest = {
    url: "",
    type: ""
}

 //Ajax call to get list items
getRequest = function (endpoint, _async) {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    var request = baseRequest;
    request.type = "GET";
    request.url = endpoint;
    request.async = _async;
    request.headers = {
        ACCEPT: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    };
    dfd = $.ajax(request);
    return dfd.promise();
};
```

Click [here](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/) to understand $.Deferred() and Deferred.Promise()

Comment: I am getting an error if I use this code. I am getting the error "baseRequest is not defined"

Comment: Now Try, "baseRequest" is variable that I have initialize